# Angular.js change location ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've read some other posts on the same topic but cannot get my own to work.  Basically, I want the location of my app to change on a ng-click event. So I have html code that looks like this:

```
<button class="button icon-left ion-plus-round button-block button-calm" ng-click="send({{foods.cal}})">
    Add Calories
</button>
```

And a controller that looks like this:

```
.controller('foodDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, foods) {
$scope.foods = foods.get($stateParams.foodsId);

$scope.send = function(i) {
// do something with 'i'

$location.path('/calc');

}

})
```

But when I click on my html button the location gets refreshed to a home tab as if it cannot find '/calc'. I've tried calc preceeded by parents folders and followed with file extension but cannot get this to work.
Any help massively appreciated.

Comment: buttons will try and submit by default - try and use e.preventDefault() in your $scope.send function

Comment: hi @deolectrix. That didn't work unfortunately. It didn't even go to the wrong location when i put that in. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Perhaps, try `'#/calc'`

Comment: @valverde93, that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: You use **angular ui-router**. And then you can use `$state.go()` function for redirection instead of `$location.path()`

Comment: @valverde93, I'm using a $urlRouteProvider. This is what my state looks like:   .state('tab.calc', {
    url: '/calc',
    views: {
      'tab-calc': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-calc.html',
        controller: 'calcCtrl'
      }
    }

Comment: @valverde93, you were right but i had forgot to add state to the controller. stupid me! thanks tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

#### in your html

```
ng-click="send($event, foods.cal)"
```

#### controller

```
$scope.send = function(event, i) {
event.preventDefault();
// do something with 'i'

$location.path('/calc');

}
```

#### you could also try using $state

instead of `$location.path('/calc')` use `$state.go('tab.calc')`

Comment: Hi @deolectrix. preventDefault() didn't work i'm afraid.

Comment: have you tried $window.location.href = '/calc'? If you have hasbangs in front of your url it would be '/#/calc'

Comment: alright since you are using ui-router try $state.go('tab.calc'); remember to inject $state into your controller

Comment: glad to help, I updated my answer, I would appreciate an upvote if it solved your problem...;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And try adding a base tag to your html head.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp